# How to organize dataset with unique customer IDs and yearly observations for regression/ML

Tags: r, data-structures, predict

I have a dataset consisting of house sales data. I want to predict sales price for a given year (response variable) based upon various attributes. The houses are assigned unique IDs, and some are sold more than one time in our timeframe. To improve precision of my predictions I want to be able to incorporate any previous sales prices and attributes to predict future house prices.

[Simple example of data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hj5y.png)

I have tried to reorganize data by having rows based upon the customer IDs:

[New formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJDwP.png)

As I have sales in different years for each house, this creates a large dataset with many NAs. This makes it difficult when performing regression/ML to predict house prices. I end up with 80 % rows with NAs, which means I have to imputate to run the algorithms, but it returns poor results.

Is there any clever way to implement each house historic sales prices and attributes when predicting prices? I have tried including unique IDs in the training and test sets (making sure the same IDs do not occur in both training and data sets), but is there a better way to organize the data to obtain better results?